# Underground condition preventing plant growth on a planet

Tags: planets, worldbuilding-process, landscaping

As title, what condition could prevent plant growth from below a planet surface?
I've considered considered removing all water from the planet, both underground and above the surface, but that doesn't feel right.
Is there any other way to completely prevent any kind of flora from growing even with abundance of water sources?

Comment: Either an absence of nutrients or trace elements or the presence of plant toxins.

Comment: Ecologists ran amok and scrubbed *all* carbon dioxide from the atmosphere? A future Elon Musk switched to lithium iron phosphate batteries and used up all the phosphorus? Global cooling froze all water? A careless alien janitor spilled a large amount of herbicide? A stupid industrial accident released a large amount of oxygen in the atmosphere?

Comment: Not sure it's possible.  Unless you have multiple conditions.  I first thought of high levels of salt in the soil, but some plants thrive in the ocean or on its edges.

Comment: Nothing! Life always finds a way, that is the whole point of evolution. Your best bet would be to not have life evolve in the first place.

Comment: "No plant growth at all" means that the only possible life is simple chemosynthesizing microbes.

Comment: @nzaman the question doesn't actually say "prevent plants but allow other life forms".  And life **doesn't** always find a way.  Just look at Mars: cold, effectively airless, sterilized by radiation and poisoned by calcium perchlorate.

Comment: @RonJohn: Or that life never evolved there because it was sterilised by radiation. If there were some underground lifeform that managed to propagate, the chances are that it would have found some way to adapt to the conditions by now.

Comment: Are we talking about Earth plants transplanted to an alien planet or naturally evolved plants?

Comment: @Real Subtle They are technically native to the planet, but they behave identically to Earth plants, so you could consider them as such

Comment: @user57841 It doesn't really work that way, the reason this matters is because of evolution which somewhat rules out options like using a substance that would be toxic to all organic life on Earth at least it would unless the introduction of the toxin is new for some reason (Maybe some subsurface microbe mutated to produce a substance that chemically destroys or deactivates chlorophyl or your biospheres equivalent). The problem is devising a reason why this trait would be advantageous enough to become common do these microbes compete with plants for resources perhaps?

Comment: @MtrJocy Yeah sorry, I could have added more details to the question. You're right though, the cause of plant extinction and not growth has been introduced artificially in the environment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given long enough timescales some lifeforms will exploit your limitations and thrive right on those constraints.

Not a solution, but a very efficient species of snails, which eat anything not snail-like, could prevent plans from growing for a long time. They would adapt to eat any naturally evolving plants, and could overcome protective mechanisms that the plants would develop. However, such a system is not perfect, and it would allow for some plans to exist at any given time. Thus the only downside is that the equilibrium is somewhere in the region of "few plants" and "many many snails".

Comment: That's something I hadn't considered, thanks!

Comment: What stops the snails starving to death once they eat all the planets...allowing the plants to recover?

Comment: Plants that mimic snails are also a very real option. Or plants toxic to those snails. Or - you know - good old thorns. Snails are surprisingly resilient to impalement, but they can't eat what they can't reach. Thorns with toxic tips in case of snails that decide whatever's being protected is worth the effort of just chewing through the defenses.

Comment: Make them worms made of silicon with a bizzare lifecycle to keep things interesting. Perhaps have them secrete something toxic in high concentrations that’s immensely valuable because of it’s mystical properties??

Answer (score 5):

Thoughts:

- Magma, lots of Magma. In essence the "surface" is very thin, perhaps 2-3 metres. There isn't soil, just basalt's and other igneous rocks. The rocks are warm to hot all the time.
- The planet is solid, no liquid iron belt protecting the planet from radiation. Sure as anything this will kill a planet. Just look at mars.

Answer (score 2):

> As title, what condition could prevent plant growth from **below a planet surface**?

Classically plants thrive on a process known as [photosynthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosynthesis) - they use energy from the sun's light in order to convert carbon and water into carbohydrates, and from there they get their energy.

Also classically the underground is a dark place that gets no sunlight<sup>[citation needed]</sup>. That should be enough to keep plants from growin in there.

Comment: I think the question is "what (that is below the surface) could prevent plant growth" and not "what is it that could prevent plants from growing while beneath the surface".

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to make the soil uninhabitable to organics due to some chemical. If this was intentional, by some advanced species, they could simply place a strong acid or poison in the ground. If this was part of the planet's nature, it could happen by the soil being incredibly acidic, dissolving most organisms before they can develop.

Comment: Chemical can come from the rocks underneath, or from acid rain. Perhaps volcanic activity could add enough chemicals to atmosphere to make rain deadly.

Comment: The problem is that Oxygen is a chemical that threatened life. Now just look at the thing. Similarly nitrite, and nitrates are poisonous and life started devouring them. Even indirect chemical poisoning like lignin (basically wood) was becoming a problem by locking up too much carbon, essentially starving all photosynthesis and you now see life happily eating that too. My point is that poisonous is purely about perspective, and easily overcome. The poison would need to be distributed everywhere, very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there isn't enough topsoil to support the growth of new plant life. This was an issue on our own planet after the end of the ice age, as moving glaciers scoured large areas as they melted in areas such as northern Canada, removing the topsoil that had existed there previously. Other examples of topsoil-removing events include high winds, abnormally heavy rainfall, and exposure to intense heat and/or radiation. So long as an event such as this occurs at a regular interval, substantial plant life should be unable to grow.

Answer (score 0):

If the soil contains (for whatever reason) no magnesium, then any life that existed couldn't make chlorophyll as we know it, which means no plants.

You could also try some kind of other organism that out-competes the plants, like a soil microbe that uses up resources instead of making them available.

An occasional catastrophic rad-blast would also do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of a couple of other answers: A toxin that actually binds the nutrients required, preventing any plant from taking them up and using them. (This is how some herbicides work today.)

This would likely affect certain non-plants, as well (microbes, fungus, etc.).
Or, perhaps a microbe *secretes* the toxin so it can monopolize the nutrients. You could develop a nasty "invasive species" story from that.

Answer (score 0):

### Soil Depletion[<sup>1</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soil_fertility#Soil_depletion)

Soil fertility depends on several factors. Changing one or more of these can inhibit that fertility:

- Sufficient soil depth for root growth and water retention.
- Good drainage
- Topsoil with proper organic matter
- Soil pH between 5.5 and 7.0
- Adequate concentrations of essential plant nutrients
- Presence of a range of microorganisms.

Disrupt any one or more variables in the above balance and your soil won't support life. For example, if some event (chemical warfare, etc.) destroys all the microbial life, then your soil won't support plants. Or make the soil acidic or basic and plants cannot grow.

Robert Heinlein touches on this briefly in *"Farmer in the Sky".* As part of their efforts to terraform Ganymede involves bringing microbial life to the moon to support plant growth (it's a minor point and not one of the major plot points at all, but the narrator talks to one of the older colonists who mentions that he has the best microbes).